# Cant scan traits of customer into customerData array

Tags: java, arrays, input, methods, shopping-cart

I am trying to make a method that allows a `Manager` or `Employee` to be able to add customers with the traits `fname`, `lname`, `address`, `city`, `state`, and `zip`. I want to store this data in `String [][] customerData = new String[30][6]`, with 30 max customers and 6 traits. However, no matter what I do, the array always ends up `null`, with nothing in it. Here is my code:

```
    public void addCustomer() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fname = "";
        String lname = "";
        String address = "";
        String city = "";
        String state = "";
        String zip = "";
        int howManyCustomers = 0;
        int traits = 6;

        System.out.println("how many customer would you like to add");
        howManyCustomers = scan.nextInt();

        for(int i=0; i < customerData.length; i++)
           {
              System.out.println("enter customer data (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip");
               for(int j=0; j < customerData[i].length; j++)
               {
                   customerData[i][j] = scan.nextLine();
               }
           }
```

Output:

```
how many customer would you like to add
1
enter customer data (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip
first name
last name
123 Address Dr
City
State
enter customer data (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip
```

It doesn't let me scan ZIP and it also loops and asks me again.
I know that none of the variables are used, but I wasn't sure if I had to use them at some point -- just kind of lost.

Comment: Please look at [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: As for the null array -- you probably need to show more pertinent code, best if you post a [mre] program inside your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if the scanner is the problem, I think its just the way that the way Im scanning it is.

Comment: Fix the scanner issue first (as per the duplicate) and then if that doesn't fix it, again post your [mre].